# Add <ul> inside existing <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a>
  <ul>
  <li>profile</li>
  <li>details</li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

I have this simple `li` in my header as menus.I am just trying to add sub list like when I click on `about` sub list should be displayed. How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? ...post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `add remove class` depending upon scenario.

```js
$("a").on("click",function(e){
 if($(e.target).attr('href') == '#about'){
    $("#add").addClass('show');
    $("#add").removeClass('hide');
 }
})
```

```css
.hide{
    display: none;
}
.show{
 display:block;
}
#add{
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a>
  <ul id="add" class="hide" >
  <li>profile</li>
  <li>details</li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
```

**Edit** As you want to appear `ul` to be on top of text after click.

Comment: its working great.But want to show it over the screen.Now when its getting open header size is getting increase and decrease based on li size.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it initially hidden and display it when `About` is clicked by changing its `display` property (`display: none` makes it hidden and `display: block` displays it).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" onClick="showAbout()">About</a>
      <ul style="display: none;" id="about">
        <li>profile</li>
        <li>details</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    function showAbout() {
      document.getElementById("about").style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to toggle the `About` submenu's visibility, you can check the `display` property of the `About` submenu each time `About` is clicked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" onClick="showAbout()">About</a>
      <ul style="display: none;" id="about">
        <li>profile</li>
        <li>details</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    function showAbout() {
      var about = document.getElementById("about");
      if (about.style.display === "none") {
        about.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        about.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its working great.But want to show it over the screen.Now when its getting open header size is getting increase and decrease based on `li` size.

Comment: @krish Could you please explain what you mean? I don't quite understand.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u3gd85cj/469/  check this.I am trying like this on `onclick`.Drop down should be displayed above the content.